# javascript array prototype - new method added - strange console.log

Tags: javascript, prototype, console.log

I'm working on a project where Array prototype has new method added:

```
Array.prototype.addOrRemove = function(value) {
    var index = _.indexOf(this, value);

    if (index === -1) {
        this.push(value);
    } else {
        this.splice(index, 1);
    }
    return this;
};
```

It either adds new value (if it's not present in the array) or removes it (otherwise). The strange thing is that when I type:

```
console.log([]);
```

I get the following output (in the chrome JS console):

```
[addOrRemove: function]
```

I thought that only values should be present in such console log. Did I do something wrong or is it a normal behavior (seems strange anyway)? I'd appreciate some explanation.

Comment: It's fine, it just tells you the custom methods that you added for convenience, if you inpect further you'll see `length:0`. In any case if you're using Underscore there's no need for that function to extend the prototype.

Comment: @elclanrs yes, I'm using underscore. Can you please explain how can I use _ instead of extending Array prototype? And why is _ better than overriding prototype?

Comment: @elclanrs - according to another SO question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474275/what-is-the-difference-between-extendsomething-prototype-someobj-and-someth), overriding prorotype with plain JS and with _ is functionally the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), which by default makes a property non-enumerable.

```
Object.defineProperty(
    Array.prototype,
    'addOrRemove',
    {
        get: function() {
            return function(value) {
                var index = _.indexOf(this, value);

                if (index === -1) {
                    this.push(value);
                } else {
                    this.splice(index, 1);
                }
                return this;
            };
        }
    }
);

console.log([]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qHFhw/1/